# How do i correctly implement serialport/parser-delimiter to electron / Angular

Tags: angular, electron

i got a problem when i use the delimeter parser from serialport. In my Backendcode in works fine. But in the Electron App i got an error..

Did i implement it correctly?

i use angular in Version 9 and electron also in Version 9.0.0, Serialport Version also 9.0.0

> i.min.js:6
> main.f7e9f04….js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

// If you import a module but never use any of the imported values other than as TypeScript types,
// the resulting javascript file will look as if you never imported the module at all.
import { ipcRenderer, webFrame, remote } from "electron";
import * as childProcess from "child_process";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as SerialPort from "serialport";
import * as DelimiterParser from "@serialport/parser-delimiter";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ElectronService {
  ipcRenderer: typeof ipcRenderer;
  webFrame: typeof webFrame;
  remote: typeof remote;
  childProcess: typeof childProcess;
  fs: typeof fs;
  serialPort: typeof SerialPort;
  delimiter: typeof DelimiterParser;
  private port;
  private parser;
  private recSerialStream: String;
  public SerialIsConnected: boolean;
  public interface: String;

  isElectron(): boolean {
    return !!(window && window.process && window.process.type);
  }

  constructor() {
    // Conditional imports
    if (this.isElectron) {
      this.ipcRenderer = window.require("electron").ipcRenderer;
      this.webFrame = window.require("electron").webFrame;
      this.remote = window.require("electron").remote;
      this.childProcess = window.require("child_process");
      this.fs = window.require("fs");
      this.serialPort = window.require("serialport");
      this.port = window.require("serialport").SerialPort;
      this.delimiter = window.require("@serialPort/parsers").Delimiter;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  connectToSerialPort(comPort) {
    if (this.isElectron && comPort > "") {
      this.port = new SerialPort(comPort, { baudRate: 115200 }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log("Error: ", err.message);
        } else {
          this.SerialIsConnected = true;
        }
      });
      this.parser = this.port.pipe(new DelimiterParser({ delimiter: "\n" }));
      this.parser.on("data", function (data) {
        const usbData: String = data + "";
        this.recSerialStream = this.recSerialStream + usbData;
        console.log(usbData);

        if (this.recSerialStream.length == 16) {
          //console.log(this.recSerialStream);
          var res = this.recSerialStream.split("_");

          this.recSerialStream = "";
        }
      });
      // this.port = new SerialPort(comPort, { baudRate: 9600 }, (err) => {
      //   if (err) {
      //     return console.log("Error: ", err.message);
      //   }
      // });
      // this.port.write("main screen turn on", function (err) {
      //   if (err) {
      //     return console.log("Error on write: ", err.message);
      //   }
      //   console.log("message written");
      // });
    }
  }

  writeSerial(data): Boolean {
    return this.port.write(Buffer.from(data + "\n"), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error on write: ", err.message);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```